# if statement in dropdown dependent on database values and user login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, drop-down-menu

My question is about a drop-down list which is dependent on the database values which has been assigned to the user which is logged in. I have used a session variable to identify the user logged in.

I would like one drop-down list to display 3 options if the user logged in has a contact ID of 1 OR 2. If the user logged in has a contact ID of 3, then a drop-down list displays with only 2 values.

My code is below which connects to the database and fetches data from a query. If the query values are not empty the first drop-down displays with 2 values, and if the query values are empty, the second drop-down displays with 3 values.

```
<?php $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'dm459', 'dm459', 
'dm459_kiamycontacts'); //This is my connection to the database

$query = "SELECT * FROM employee WHERE contactID = 3 AND 
               employeeUsername = '" .$_SESSION['User'] . "' LIMIT 1"; 
    //This is the query to the database

                $result1 = mysqli_query($connect, $query); ?>

                <select id="dropdown">
        <?php $row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1);

                    if(!empty($row1)) { ?>
                    <option class="select" value="0">Kia Academy</option>
                    <option class="select" value="1">
                     Dealer Development</option> <?php }

                    elseif (empty($row1)) { ?>
                    <option class="select" value="0">Kia Academy</option>
                    <option class="select" value="1">
                    Dealer Development</option>
                    <option class="select" value="2">Dealership</option>
                <?php } ?>

                </select>
```

Comment: Then use `$row1['contactID']` as the decision in your conditional statement.

Answer (score 0):

Using contact ID, you could do this:

```
if(3 == $row1['contactID']) {
   // display 2 options
} elseif(2 == $row1['contactID'] || 1 == $row1['contactID']) {
  // display 3 options
}
```

Comment: When using the above code, no options are displayed in the drop-down list.

Comment: You have to replace the comments with the options you want to display.

Comment: Hi Jay, yes I did this and its still not working.                                                               
if(3 == $row1['contactID']) { ?>
          <option class="select" value="0">Kia Academy</option>
       <option class="select" value="1">Dealer Development</option> <?php
      
      } elseif(2 == $row1['contactID'] || 1 == $row1['contactID']) { ?>
         <option class="select" value="0">Kia Academy</option>
                      <option class="select" value="1">Dealer Development</option>
                      <option class="select" value="2">Dealership</option>

Comment: I apologies. When I say "still not working" I mean that the dropdown list now shows without any options available

Comment: What are the columns in your employee table?